# How do I attach CSS to the mail() method in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, email

I have an email sent to the user when they have forgotten their password with this php code:

```
<?php
//OTHER CODE BEFORE ALL THIS

$to = "$useremail";
$from = "forgotpassword@mysite.com";
$headers ="From: $from\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \n";

$subject = 'Temporary Password';
$msg = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Message</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div>Temporary Password</div>
  <p>Hello<b> '.$f.'</b>,</p>
  <p>You indicated that you forgot your login password. We can generate a temporary password for you to log in with, then once logged in you can change your password to anything you like.</p>
  <p>After you click the link below your password to login will be:</p>
  <p><b>'.$tempPass.'</b></p>
  <div style="margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center;">
    <p><a style="   background: #f3c1e6;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#f3c1e6), to(#de66c0));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f3c1e6, #de66c0);
    background: linear-gradient(#f3c1e6, #de66c0);
    border: solid 1px #cd5daf;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #ce5eb0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #e998d3;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ce5eb0;
    zoom: 1;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset;
    der-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;" href="http://www.bragmouth.com/forgot_pass.php?u='.$u.'&p='.$hashTempPass.'">Click Here to Apply</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
';
if(mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers)) {
echo 'true';
exit();
} else {
echo 'false';
exit();
}
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

My problem is I cannot add any CSS to this email by way of Internal or External stylesheets. However, I can add Inline style to any tag in the HTML. Do I need to change the Content-type to text/css or can I have two content types?

Also, I cannot get gradients to show up in yahoo mail (which is probably their fault). I can get them to show up in google mail, except for links (which is why I posted the links style). Is this google's fault as well? Can this all be solved by attaching a stylesheet?

Comment: Email clients have extremely outdated rendering engines — and some, like google, do not support referenced stylesheets — the content type will be little effect on ensuring the mail client parse the reference stylesheet. To ensure uniform appearance, you should use inline CSS. Given the first point, I would expect few clients to support CSS3 gradients — you might want to look at using a background image instead.

Comment: unfortunately you can't attach css file

Comment: Terry - It looks like I'm going to have to use a background image to achieve the look I want with the gradients. I just hope these email clients support background images now.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using css styles in your email html. Outlook does some weird stuff with their CSS (they even change your HTML to add their custom classes) and I believe Gmail strips out the head tags tags.

There's a tool I use to convert CSS to inline styles:

[Css Inliner](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)

Comment: I really like this CSS Inliner, it saves a lot of time when I need it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** build your mail-headers yourself since there are so many little things which can go wrong. Just use a widely used and tested mailer like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Then you can add a css-file as attachment to the mail and directly use it in the mail, see [Here](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#embedding-inline-media-files).

Edit: Okay, i was wrong, this won't work with CSS files, but you can convert your HTML-File with normal css to a html-file with inlined css, see [Here](https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles)

Comment: I've looked at swiftmailer and I think I rather go with my own code. Thanks anyway tkausl!